# I accidentally deleted a volume in my HDD, can I still recover it?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I need your help to see if it is possible to recover the data from a HDD that I accidentally damaged using diskpart. Well I explain in summary how everything happened. Yesterday I decided to install Windows 10 on a SSD (120GB); besides that SSD I have a HDD (1TB) where I have all my files stored. To install Windows 10 I used an USB stick that I managed to boot correctly using the UEFI option. Once inside the Windows installation program, in the part where you need to select the drive where you want to install it, I selected the SSD but it gave me an error that said the unit was in MBR and I needed to convert it to GPT. So following a tutorial that I found online, I did this from the CMD:

> **diskpart**
>
> **list disk**
>
> *- disk 0 (SSD) 120gb*
>
> *- disk 1 (HDD) 1tb (it has 2 partitions, the 1st in 900gb and the other 100gb)*
>
> **select disk 0**
>
> **clean**
>
> **create part pri**
>
> **select part 1**
>
> **format fs=ntfs**
>
> **select disk 0**
>
> **detail disk**
>
> **select volume 1** *(this is where I think I made the mistake, volume 1
>   was the 1st partition of disk 1 HDD I think, I didn't check it)*
>
> **delete volume**
>
> **convert gpt** *(here it gave me an error and could not convert to GPT)*

Then I went back to the installer of Windows 10 and again in the part where it asks you to select the unit where you are going to install Windows was when I realized the damage I had done. Not only I was not able to convert the SSD to GPT but also accidentally deleted the volume of the HDD (1st partition of 900gb) where I had my files; the 2nd partition was not damaged. Now I do not know if everything I had in that partition was deleted or there is still a way to recover it.

Using GParted program from Linux I took a capture of the current state of the HDD. You can see the "sin asignar" (unassigned) partition with 833.86 GB. Is this recoverable?
[image: HDD unassigned]

By the way, I already managed to convert the SSD to GPT and install Windows 10 correctly, but this time of course, I did it by disconnecting the HDD to avoid doing more damage. Currently I still have it disconnected.

I would like to know what I can do to try to recover that HDD partition. The "delete volume" command is the same as doing a format or it can be recovered?

I would appreciate if you could help me. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

TestDisk by cgsecurity.
Make sure not to save any thing to the drive to be recovered.

1. download
2. extract
3. run testdisk as admin
4. No log  (You can log if you want to)
5. select a disk
6. Intel
7. Analyse  ] Analyse current partition structure and search for lost partitions
8. Quick search

If it finds it.

9. **A** add partition

Else
 Extended search will take a long time

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, I just need a little more time to learn about how it works. Also to know what are all my options since I'll probably only have one chance to try to fix it.

Comment: This should be the perfect way to restore a table that was removed by an accident with the windows partition tool ("select disk <foo>; clean"). Thank you very much!